# What is the most obfuscated code you've had to fix?

Tags: debugging, obfuscation

Most programmers will have had the experience of debugging/fixing someone else's code. Sometimes that "someone else's code" is so obfuscated it's bad enough trying to understand what it's doing.

What's the worst (most obfuscated) code you've had to debug/fix?

If you didn't throw it away and recode it from scratch, well why didn't you?

Comment: I checked the "community wiki" box. Hope I did it right...I'm new here.

Comment: thanks, reopened. Not a huge fan of the question, but.. it is based on real world experiences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- a Java class
- only static methods that manipulates DOM
- 8000 LOCs
- long chain of methods that return null on "error": a.b().c().d().e()
- very long methods (400/500 LOC each)
- nested if, while, like:

  ```
  if (...) {
    for (...) {
      if (...) {
        if (...) {
          while (...) {
            if (...) {
  ```
- cut-and-paste oriented programming
- no exceptions, all exceptions are catched and "handled" using printStackTrace()
- no unit tests
- no documentation

I was tempted to throw away and recode... but, after 3 days of hard debugging,
I've added **the magic if** :-)

Comment: lol!! the magic if! gotta love that phrase. I'm in kinda similar situation, except it's a hobby, and I'm throwing away and recoding. There's no magic if in my case.

Comment: Hahaha, +1 for *cut-and-paste oriented programming*

Answer (score 10):

PHP OSCommerce is enough to say, it is obfuscated code...

Answer (score 2):

Spaghetti code PHP CMS system.

Answer (score 2):

by default, programmers think someone else's code is obfuscated.

The worse I probably had to do was interpreting what variables i1, i2 j, k, t were in a simple method and they were not counters in 'for' loops.

In all other circumstances I guess the problem area was difficult which made the code look difficult.

Comment: Conversely: by default, programmers think their code is self-documenting and doesn't need commenting.

Comment: I disagree.  I know some of my code is really bad and looks obfuscated.  And I've seen a great many badly written code (not by me).  But I've also seen very clean code: I don't think that a clean code is obfuscated when I see one.  Truth is: most programmers (including me and, statistically speaking, probably you) write poor code but there definitely are programmers who write outstanding code.  And such code doesn't look obfuscated to an honest programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I found this line in our codebase today and thought it was a nice example of sneaky obfuscation:

```
if (MULTICLICK_ENABLED.equals(propService.getProperty(PropertyNames.MULTICLICK_ENABLED))) {} else {
    return false;
}
```

Just making sure I read the whole line. NO SKIMREADING.

Answer (score 1):

When working on a GWT project, I would reach parts of GWT-compiled obfuscated JS code which wasn't mine.

Now good luck debugging *real* obfuscated code.

Comment: with GWT that should be considered the object code and not source. The two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the full code, but a single part of it remains burned into my memory as something I spend hours trying to understand:

```
do{
  $tmp = shift unless shift;
  $tmp;
}while($tmp);
```

I couldn't understand it at first, it looks so useless, then I printed out @_ for a list of arguments, a series of alternating boolean and function names, the code was used in conjunction with a library detection module that changed behaviour if a function was broken, but the code was so badly documented and made of things like that which made no sense without a complete understanding of the full code I gave up and rewrote the whole thing.

---

UPDATE from DVK:

And, lest someone claims this was because Perl is unreadable as opposed to coder being a golf master instead of good software developer, here's the same code in a slightly less obfuscated form (the really correct code wouldn't even HAVE alternating sub names and booleans in the first place :)

```
# This subroutine take a list of alternating true/false flags
# and subroutine names; and executes the named subroutines for which flag is true.
# I am also weird, otherwise I'd have simply have passed list of subroutines to execute :)
my @flags_and_sub_names_list = @_;
while ( @flags_and_sub_names_list ) {
    my $flag     = shift @flags_and_sub_names_list; 
    my $subName  = shift @flags_and_sub_names_list;
    next unless $flag && $subName;
    &{ $subName }; # Call the named subroutine
}
```

Comment: OK, I give up. How the hell did that even work? You can't call a function by putting a variable containing its name as a statement in Perl. Unless the third line was actually `&{$tmp}` ???

Answer (score 0):

I've had a case of a 300lines function performing input sanitization which missed a certain corner case. It was parsing certain situations manually using IndexOf and Substring plus a lot of inlined variables and constants (looks like the original coder didn't know anything about good practices), and no comment was provided. Throwing it away wasn't feasible due to time constraints and the fact that I didn't have the specification required so rewriting it would've meant understanding the original, but after understanding it fixing it was just quicker. I also added lots of comments, so whoever shall come after me won't feel the same pain taking a look at it...

Comment: what do you mean by "inlined variables"?

Comment: recurring expressions that should have been factored out into variables rather than repeated time and time again, cluttering the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl statement:

```
select((select(s),$|=1)[0])
```

which, at the suggestion of the original author (Randal Schwartz himself, who said he disliked it but nothing else was available at the time), was replaced with something a little more understandable:

```
IO::Handle->autoflush
```

Beyond that one-liner, some of the Java JDBC libraries from IBM are obfuscated and all variables and functions are either combinations of the letter 'l' and '1' or single/double characters - very hard to track anything down until you get them all renamed. Needed to do this to track down why they worked fine in IBM's JRE but not Sun's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about HLL codes, once I was updating project written by a chinese and all comments were chinese (stored in ansii) and it was a horror to understand some code fragments, if you're talking about low level code there were *MANY* of them (obfuscated, mutated, vm-ed...).

Answer (score 0):

I once had to reverse engineer a Java 1.1 framework that:

1. Extended event-driven SAX parser classes for every class, even those that didn't parse XML (the overridden methods were simply invoked ad hoc by other code)
2. Custom runtime exceptions were thrown in lieu of method invocations wherever possible. As a result, most of the business logic landed in a nested series of `catch` blocks.

If I had to guess, it was probably someone's "smart" idea that method invocations were expensive in Java 1.1, so throwing exceptions for non-exceptional flow control was somehow considered an optimization.

Went through about three bottles of eye drops.

Answer (score 0):

I once found a time bomb that had been intentionally obfuscated.

When I had finally decoded what it was doing I mentioned it to the manager who said they knew about the time bomb but had left it in place because it was so ineffective and was interwoven with other code.

The time bomb was (presumably) supposed to go off after a certain date.

Instead, it had a bug in it so it only activated if someone was working after lunchtime on Dec 31st.

It had taken three years for that circumstance to occur since the guy who wrote the time bomb left the company.